# How do I get fgets to receive user input?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm new to coding C and stackoverflow. I was doing some practice after a lesson and I can't figure this particular issue out. The program concludes without fgets receiving input from the user. Please help.

```
int main(){
printf("Welcome to the Basic Calculator.\nThis lets you input two numbers and the sum will be displayed on the computer screen.\n\n");
double firstNumber;
double secondNumber;
char rating[3];
char feedback[50];
printf("Please enter the first number\n");
scanf("%lf", &firstNumber);
printf("Please enter the second number\n");
scanf("%lf", &secondNumber);
printf("The sum of %f and %f is %f\n\n", firstNumber, secondNumber, firstNumber + secondNumber);
printf("Thank you for using the Basic Calculator. Are you pleased with the result?\n");
scanf("%s", rating);
printf("\nYou said %s. Please provide some feedback.", rating);
fgets(feedback, 50, stdin);
printf("Your feedback is %s. We will improve. Bye!", feedback);

return 0;
```

}

This is the result from the terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1ucD.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Have you successfully followed any tutorial on the matter? If yes, can you point out the difference you intentionally appled from the working example code to the code you are showing?

Comment: What do you mean by "without the last fgets working"? No data? Wrong data? Crash? Hang?

Comment: The shown code is not a [mre]. It at least lacks includes and information on input and result.

Comment: What do you mean by "last fgets"? There is only one. Does the program work if you remove all scanf calls?

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`. Replace all your `scanf()`s with `fgets(); sscanf()`

Comment: I have edited properly and added an image of the code output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program is skipping fgets without allowing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247514/program-is-skipping-fgets-without-allowing-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` leaves `\n` made by the press to `Return`/`Enter` in `stdin`.

The `scanf()` calls in your code catch those left newline character from the previous calls because they skip leading white space (such as tab, newline or just plain white space) in `stdin`, but opposed to that `fgets()` does not skip leading white space characters.

This newline character is fetched by `fgets()`, which stops consuming input from `stdin` until it encounters a newline.

The result is that only the `\n` newline character is taken by the call to `fgets()`.

To catch the abandoned newline you could either use `getchar();` or `scanf("%*c");` before the call to `fgets()`:

```
scanf("%s", rating);
printf("\nYou said %s. Please provide some feedback.", rating);

getchar();                         // catching newline character.

fgets(feedback, 50, stdin);
```

---

Side note: Don´t intermix calls to `fgets()` with `scanf()`. Catch either all input as strings by using `fgets()` and thereafter parse them with `sscanf()` or use `scanf()` consistently.

Comment: Thank you very much. `getchar()` works perfectly. I will study this in more detail. You mentioned using `scanf("%*c")`. Which position will that be relative to my code? 
`scanf("%*c");
    
scanf("%s", rating);
    
printf("\nYou said %s. Please provide some feedback.", rating);
    
fgets(feedback, 50, stdin);`

Comment: @codingisfun The same position as `getchar()`. Note that only one of them two is useful. They are alternatives to each other. - `scanf("%*c")` basically means "*Take a character from `stdin` and discard it*". You also could add it to the previous `scanf()` call like: `scanf("%s%*c", rating);`.

Comment: @codingisfun I´m glad, that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` with a '%s' format reads a single space-delimited word, and leaves any space following the one read word in the input buffer.

i.e. if you input a rating of "good" and press enter, `scanf` will read the word "good" and leave the following newline character in the input buffer. When you then get to `fgets` it will read anything up to the first newline character, which in this case is nothing at all as the first thing `fgets` sees is the newline left there by `scanf`.

To solve this problem you could read what is left in the input buffer by `scanf`, up to and including the newline character before calling `fgets`.

Comment: Okay, so how is this done? I haven't gotten this far in the course.

Comment: "*To solve this problem you could read...*" - Consider Beginner -> Provide an example.